# Как проверить поставлена ли галочка в QCheckBox

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, checkbox, сигналы-слоты

Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить поставлена ли галочка в `QCheckBox`?

Мне нужно, если галочка поставлена выполнилось действие, но я никак не могу проверить.

Вроде вот так:

```
class ReservationRoom(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_RoomRes):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        if self.sender() == self.checkBox_1:
            ...
```

Спасибо за любые советы.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_checkboxes.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается всякий раз, когда состояние флажка изменяется, то есть всякий раз, когда пользователь проверяет или снимает его.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class ReservationRoom(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('one')
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('two')
        
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_1)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        
        self.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state=self.checkBox_1.isChecked(), no=1: self.selectBooks(state, no))
        self.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state=self.checkBox_2.isChecked(), no=2: self.selectBooks(state, no))

    def selectBooks(self, toggle, no):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('toggle=`{}`, checked_{}'.format(toggle, no))
            if no == 1:
                print('checked_{} -> галочка поставлена выполнилось действие'.format(no))
        else:
            print('toggle=`{}`, unchecked_{}'.format(toggle, no))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ReservationRoom()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте! Почему toggle всегда равен 0, либо 2?

Comment: @User , здравствуйте, задайте новый вопрос, покажите ваш код, расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.