# Как определить, что checkBox активирован?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как определить, что `CheckBox` активирован?

Допустим, если `checkBox` активен, то выводилось 1, если не активно, то 2.

Как это сделать? Активным я считаю, если на виджете есть "галочка".

```
с = #определение состояния
if c == #есть "галочка":
   x = 5
elif c == #нет "галочки":
   x = 10
print(x)

#что-то не так
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(959, 365)
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 230, 421, 41))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(23, 30, 441, 41))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(494, 20, 421, 61))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 421, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 80, 431, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 164, 421, 21))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(493, 160, 421, 31))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(21, 190, 421, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(489, 190, 431, 41))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 901, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 87 26pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state=self.checkBox.isChecked(), no=1: self.selectBooks(state, no))

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "Использовать тот же путь"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи путь до исходного файла"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи название исходного файла"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи путь до конечного файла"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи название конечного файла"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Конвертировать"))




app = QApplication([])

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        file = str(self.lineEdit.text()) + "/" + str(self.lineEdit_2)
        def selectBooks(self, toggle, no):
            if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                print('toggle=`{}`, checked_{}'.format(toggle, no))
                if no == 1:
                    print('checked_{} -> галочка поставлена выполнилось действие'.format(no))
            else:
                print('toggle=`{}`, unchecked_{}'.format(toggle, no))

mw = Main()
mw.show()


app.exec()
```

Comment: только что ответил на ваш вопрос, посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061822/pyqt5-checkbox . Если что-то не понятно - спросите.

Comment: Спасибо! Единственное не понял, как указать, какой checkBox отслеживать?

Comment: В том примере  `self.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state=self.checkBox_1.isChecked(), no=1: self.selectBooks(state, no))`  - `no=1` это первый checkBox. Опубликуйте ваш приме и я подправлю если что ни так.

Comment: я опубликовал код, видимо что-то напутал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Никогда не изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer**

`selectBooks` метод  `class Main` сдвинули на 4 позиции влево.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(959, 365)
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 230, 421, 41))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(23, 30, 441, 41))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(494, 20, 421, 61))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 421, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 80, 431, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 164, 421, 21))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(493, 160, 421, 31))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(21, 190, 421, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(489, 190, 431, 41))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 901, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 87 26pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "Использовать тот же путь"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи путь до исходного файла"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи название исходного файла"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи путь до конечного файла"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи название конечного файла"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Конвертировать"))


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        file = str(self.lineEdit.text()) + "/" + str(self.lineEdit_2)

        # Никогда не изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state=self.checkBox.isChecked(), no=1: self.selectBooks(state, no))

#   <---- это метод  class Main сдвинули на 4 позиции влево  
    def selectBooks(self, toggle, no):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('toggle=`{}`, checked_{}'.format(toggle, no))
            if no == 1:
                print('checked_{} -> галочка поставлена выполнилось действие'.format(no))
        else:
            print('toggle=`{}`, unchecked_{}'.format(toggle, no))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    mw = Main()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]